# how to bypass download chef-client-latest when knife bootstrap a node windows

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra, knife

when i knife bootstrap a windows node, it always download a chef-client-latest.msi but i already installed chef-client on that node. Have any ways to bypass this step?

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm ADDRESS --winrm-authentication-protocol basic -x admin -P pass --node-name nodename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like this is built-in to the knife-windows plugin. The best I can suggest is to pass your own [installer command](https://github.com/chef/knife-windows/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/windows-chef-client-msi.erb#L110) and make it a no-op. As far as I can tell, there's no way to disable this behavior, unless you can make an MSI install action be idempotent. Are you really running bootstraps that often that this is a major impact? Perhaps there's an alternative workflow that doesn't involve rebootstrapping a server.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i need to bypass that because i get low internet connection and i have the package i dont want it download erverytime, this waste time.